# How to diagnose why Azure websites keep going down

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a few websites hosted as Azure websites. They are all in the same App service plan so I assume they are on the same machine/application pool.

I have a website monitor that pings the server every 5 mins to check they are online. Every week or so all the websites seem to go down for a couple of minutes as though the application pool crashes and restarts.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is this normal?

What can I do to find out why this happens?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously it is not normal for the websites to go down for no reason.

To check the availability and getting notified on down times you can use Azure AppInsights to check the health of your web sites:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-monitor-web-app-availability/

To find out what causes it you can enable Web Server Diagnostics as well as Application Diagnostics for your websites and check the logs when this happens again.

Here is the reference on how to enable these:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/

Comment: Thanks. I will do that.. Will I have to enable the web server logs for every site? Or is it shared? I'll add application insights or new relic to the rest of them.

Comment: Each website will have it's own diagnostics settings, so should be enabled separately..

Comment: @dontbesorry80 So, how dit it go?